# Logic. Having problems with interpretations

Tags: logic

My question asks me to specify a true and a false interpretation over the domain {1,2,3} of

(∃x¬Fx → ¬∃xFx)

So I have said that the extensions of a,b,c are 1,2,3
Do I just need to find extensions of F that make the statement true or false?

Like for the true statement if I say the extension of F is {1,2,3} then does that mean ∃x¬Fx is False and therefore the conditional is true?

Comment: Correct: you have to specify (i) an interpretation of **F** in the said domain that satisfies (make it *true*) the formula and (ii) an interpretation of **F** in the said domain that falsifies (make it *false*) the formula. And your choice for (i) is good.

Answer (score 1):

Since one knows there is a true and false interpretation for *∃x¬Fx → ¬∃xFx* one could use a tree proof generator to find an interpretation that makes the statement false.  Here is such a result:

[image]

For this countermodel *x=b* makes the antecedent, *∃x¬Fx*, true, but there also exists an element of the domain, *a*, that makes *F* true and so the consequent is false. Hence the conditional is false.

The problem has another constraint: Use the domain *{1, 2, 3}*.

What we need to do is provide two structures using this domain, one leading to a true result and the other to a false result.  The [Open Logic Project](http://builds.openlogicproject.org/open-logic-complete.pdf) defines a "structure *M*, for a language *L* of first-order logic consists of the following elements": (Definition 12.26)

1. A non-empty domain.
2. An interpretation of constant symbols.
3. An interpretation of predicate symbols.
4. An interpretation of function symbols.

Using the result from the tree proof generator as a guide and following this definition of structure, the following is an interpretation leading to a false result:

- Domain: {1,2,3}
- Constant symbols:

  - a: 1
  - b: 2
  - c: 3
- Predicate symbols:

  - F: {a}
- Function symbols: (There are none in this exercise.)

For an interpretation leading to a true result, use the above but change the interpretation of the predicate symbol, as the OP suggests, to *F:{a,b,c}*. Then the antecedent is false since there does not exist an element of the domain that makes *F* false and so the conditional is true.

---

Open Logic Project https://openlogicproject.org/

Tree Proof Generator. Retrieved on June 9, 2019 from https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/